# How do I clear all recent apps using ADB in one command?

Tags: adb

I am looking for a one liner solution that make use of adb to clear all recent apps, similar to clicking the overview button the click 'clear all'. Does anyone happen to know one?

My guess is that it must have something got to do with the com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity

Comment: Try these steps, it's already answered.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898029/adb-how-to-tap-close-from-recent-apps-to-completelty-through-adb-one-liner-comm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898029/adb-how-to-tap-close-from-recent-apps-to-completelty-through-adb-one-liner-comm)

Comment: Try these steps, it's already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898029/adb-how-to-tap-close-from-recent-apps-to-completelty-through-adb-one-liner-comm

Comment: Thanks for the reply munsoft004. Unfortunately the solution given is not what I am looking for. I want a solution that does not simulate keyevent but clear ALL recent apps in one command. Does anyone knows if this can be done?